# How can I create a timestamp for multiple tabs in a single new tab. google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, spread

Hi I have a tab with all the tab names, I want to include the date/time the row in that sheet was last updated.
E.g:

| Sheet name | Updated on |
| --- | --- |
| Sheet 1 | 16/05/2022 14:20 |
| Sheet 2 | 15/05/2022 11:20 |

Is it possible to timestamp multiple sheets into one separate sheet?

Comment: As far as I know a sheet has no property modified date or something like that. So you can't gather the dates of last modification. But you can add a trigger `onEdit()` or `onChange()` to the spreadsheet that will write the current date in some cell (say on the first sheet) every time as someone edits any of the sheets in this spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to protect the timestamp sheet against unintended modifications, a simple `onEdit(e)` trigger will not work. Instead, run the timestamp function on an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), like this:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
'use strict';


/**
* Inserts a table in timestamp.sheet that lists the latest modification
* date recorded for each sheet in the spreadsheet.
*
* Timestamps are only recorded when the spreadsheet is hand modified.
*
* To install a trigger to run this function, click the clock icon
* in the left in Extensions > Apps Script, then click Add trigger > 
* sheetModicationTimestamps > Head > From spreadsheet > on edit > Save.
*
* @param {Object} e The 'on edit' event object.
*/
function sheetModicationTimestamps(e) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 May 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72259914/13045193
  'use strict';
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Install a trigger to run this function.');
  }
  try {
    const timestamp = {
      sheetName: 'Sheet modification dates',
      rangeA1: 'C1:D',
      format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
    };
    const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    if (sheetName === timestamp.sheetName) {
      return;
    }
    const now = new Date();
    timestamp.sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(timestamp.sheetName);
    if (!timestamp.sheet) {
      timestamp.sheet = e.source.insertSheet(timestamp.sheetName);
      timestamp.sheet.getRange(timestamp.rangeA1)
        .offset(0, 0, 1, 2)
        .setValues([['Sheet name', 'Updated on']]);
    }
    timestamp.range = timestamp.sheet.getRange(timestamp.rangeA1);
    timestamp.values = timestamp.range.getValues().filter(row => String(row[0]));
    const rowIndex = timestamp.values.map(row => row[0]).indexOf(sheetName);
    if (rowIndex === -1) {
      timestamp.values = timestamp.values.concat([[sheetName, now]]);
    } else {
      timestamp.values[rowIndex][1] = now;
    }
    timestamp.range
      .clearContent()
      .offset(0, 0, timestamp.values.length, 2)
      .setValues(timestamp.values)
      .setNumberFormat(timestamp.format);
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(error.message, 'sheetModicationTimestamps', 30);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheet_name = sheet.getName();
  if (sheet_name == 'Timestamps') return; // do nothing if it's 'Timestamps' sheet

  var date = new Date();

  var timestamps_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Timestamps');
  var sheets_names = timestamps_sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues().flat();  
  var row = sheets_names.indexOf(sheet_name) + 1;

  if (row > 0) {
    timestamps_sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(date);
    ss.toast('Row ' + row + ' was updated');
  } else {
    timestamps_sheet.appendRow([sheet_name, date]);
    ss.toast('A new row was added');
  }
}
```

The script adds or modifies the timestamps on the sheet 'Timestamps' every time you make changes on other sheets of the spreadsheet.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KiwLqezAanI1sLJDqplfEOPbnylhr9PXy8eZKFyMgPU/edit?usp=sharing) is my spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks a lot for your comment!
Unfortunately I am getting the following error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined".

Do you know why this maybe?

Comment: I think it's because you're trying to run the script from Script Editor. It works another way. The `onEdit()` function fires automatically whenever you edit cells of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you! I have made changes however this is not displayed on the Timestamps tab.

Comment: Did you try my sheet (you can make copy of it) or you did copy the script into your Spreadsheet?

Comment: I copied the script into my spreadsheet.

Comment: This is mean you have something special in your spreadsheet then. It hard to tell what it could be. I can try to figure it out if you share your spreadsheet (or its exactly copy without sensitive data)

Comment: Works perfect now! Thank you so much Yuri :))